# Show whether the function $\phi(x)=21x \bmod 36$ is one-to-one and/or onto

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, congruences, group-homomorphism

Let $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{36} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{36}$ and define $\phi(x)=21x\bmod36$.

I have already shown that the function is a homomorphism. I am having trouble showing whether it is one-to-one and/or onto.

So far I have for one-to-one:

Let $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_{36}$ and let $\phi(x_1)=\phi(x_2)$. Then $21x_1\bmod36$ = $21x_2\bmod36$. I am unsure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove it because it is false. Note that $\phi(0)=\phi(12)$, but $0\neq12$. And it is not surjective.

Comment: so to disprove it am i able to just show the counterexample?

Comment: @rover2 Nothing prevents you from showing two or more counterexamples, but showing one is enough, yes.

Comment: i know that if we let $x_1=0$, then $0\bmod36=36$, but how does $\phi(12)=36$?

Comment: is it just $36=252(0)+36$?

Comment: @rover2 $\phi(12)=21\times12\pmod{36}\equiv7\times36\pmod{36}\equiv0\pmod{36}$.

Comment: how is it not surjective?

Comment: @rover2 $\phi$ is a function from a set with $36$ elements into itself. Since it is not injective, it cannot be surjective.

Comment: that doesnt make sense

Comment: @rover2 Why not?

Comment: if $\phi$ is a function from a set with 36 elements to the same set of 36 elements how is it not onto...

Comment: @rover2 For instance, the function $\psi\colon\{0,1,\ldots,35\}\longrightarrow\{0,1,\ldots,35\}$ defined by $\psi(x)=0$ is a function from a set with $36$ elements into itself which is not onto.

Comment: so this is how i have it worded so far...i want to show that $\forall t \in \mathbb{Z}_{36}$ (codomain) that I can find (if possible) a $s$ in the domain such that $\phi(s)=t$. Then $\phi(s)=21s\bmod36=t$. Where would I go from here to show we can't find such a $s$.?

Comment: @rover2 From there, I don't know. I never said that there is no such $s$ *ever*. What I wrote was that $\phi$ is not onto, which means that for *some* $t$ there is no $s$ such that $\phi(s)=t$.